# python xpath get value while its parallel's child value matches

Tags: python, xml, xpath

```
    <multi-routing-engine-item>

        <re-name>n</re-name>

        <zones-information xmlns="http://xml48/juzones" j:s="de">
            <zones-security>
                <zones-security-zonename>HH</zones-security-zonename>
                <zones-security-interfaces>
                    <zones-security-interface-name>2.66</zones-security-interface-name>
                    <zones-security-interface-name>2.68</zones-security-interface-name>
                </zones-security-interfaces>
            </zones-security>
            <zones-security>        
                <zones-security-zonename>BB</zones-security-zonename>
```

I want to get  HH(zones-security-zonename) when zones-security-interface-name is 2.66

Treid many ways . no luck to make it work

This is my try:

```
multi-routing-engine-item/zones-information/zones-security[zones-security-interfaces/zones-security-interface-name='2.66']/zones-security-zonename
```

Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the element:

```
//zones-security[.//zones-security-interface-name[text()='2.66']]/zones-security-zonename
```

To get text:

add `/text()` in the end

Logic is simple:
search `zones-security` that contains `zones-security-interface-name` with `[text()='2.66']`. And in found zone - get `/zones-security-zonename`

Comment: follow your instruction,and it works:                                                                  >>> response_zone.xpath("//zones-security[.//zones-security-interface-name[text()='2.66']]/zones-security-zonename/text()")
['HH']    .

Comment: great) mark answer as correct if it works), or update your question with correct answer to help others

Comment: marked.  But why response_zone.findtext("multi-routing-engine-item/zones-information/zones-security[.//zones-security-interface-name[text()='2.66']]/zones-security-zonename") doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try the xpath :

`//zones-security-interface-name[.='2.66']/preceding::zones-security-zonename/text()`

Comment: bad idea to use `parent::*` (which is actually is `/../`) directly, as in case element will be nested inside another layer - path won't work.  Better to use `preceding::zones-security-interfaces` in that case

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks for the comment !

Comment: Well done, i'll vote for your path, though it has one issue. In case `zones-security-zonename` will be missing inside found `zones-security` - path will find previous elements. So in case you are 100% sure element will be inside - this path is OK. In other case - better to find  `zones-security` that has needed text and search `zones-security-zonename` inside of it, to be sure correct element is found)

Comment: Ok as you said, lets say `zones-security-zonename` is moved above `zones-security` ( it has to be somewhere right ? ) and you want to still get the value, how will you do it ? Also consider this : Lets say you removed the parent `zones-security-interfaces`, how will you get the value? There was no requirement that it cannot be inside the `zone-security`. BTW upvoted your answer too.

Comment: The point is: does author need to ensure that file structure was not changed? If yes - your answer is better, because your path has some hidden checks for elements relations. If no - my answer is better, as it just checks, that inside some` zones-security` both of these 2 elements should be located in any order/at any level. 
p.s. i'm usually writing locators to be structure independent, because they are easier to support for me, as qa-automation engineer